# How to create the V8 object in another thread, then copy it back into nodejs scope?

Tags: node.js, v8, libuv

I have to parse very long JSON text into JSON object. 
I tried to measure the executing time with following code.

```
var t = process.hrtime()
JSON.parse(jsonStr);
t = process.hrtime(t);
```

It takes about 0.5 millisecond,  that is quite a lot. because the nodejs is single-threaded for its V8 Engine, if this operation is so heavy & frequent, the throughput will be impacted much.

Hence I plan to write an asynchronous JSON.parse in C as a NodeJS native addon, using `uv_queue_work` to let the heavy operation happens in another thread, taking use the multi-core and avoid taking up the nodejs main loop.

The problem is, the V8 object in nodeJS is not allowed to be accessed from other thread than main thread.

Is there any way that I can parse the text and create the V8 object in another thread, then copy the new created V8 object into the main thread ?

Br

Comment: I was also thinking about this problem, I tried to implement an asynchronous json parser in JavaScript ( https://github.com/micnic/simpleS/blob/503eba4f7b8e2c397b7d895241be46dc01f6d80b/utils/parsers/json.js ), but the performance relative to the native JSON.parse is quite low. Hope you will have more luck with an native addon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there any way that I can parse the text and create the V8 object in another thread, then copy the new created V8 object into the main thread ?

There is no good way to do that.

If you want to use all cores, it's better to spawn multiple node.js processes using `cluster` module and let each of them handle different requests.